# Does "time.sleep()" not work inside a for loop with a print function using the "end" attribute?

Tags: python

So, I'm just recently learning python and I was playing with some code. I wanted to print the some character without line breaks over a loop with some delay. I used the time.sleep() function inside the for loop. But, all it does is delay the output for the total time it would have taken in the loop, all at once and, then print out the character.

I did try it without the "end" attribute and it worked perfectly. But, I didn't want the line break.

```
from time import sleep
print("starting the progress bar")


for i in range(50):
    sleep(0.1)
    print("#", end = '')
```

I expected the output to print a character and with a delay, print another character. But, the script delays for 0.1 seconds for 50 times and then prints out all the characters at once

Comment: Are you sure your ```print``` statement is not outside of the for loop? Be careful with indentation

Comment: @NicLaforge Yes, there are no indentation mistakes in the code.

Comment: Not sure why @tawab_shakeel modified your code in the question, as he edited with the proper answer. I have looked at your original code and your print was outside the loop

Comment: @NicLaforge i  just put the code in code block otherwise the question was not in a readable format

Comment: @thesuzan you have option not to accept the edit if you feel the edit is not properly done by any other user

Comment: @NicLaforge I assure you that there are no indentation mistakes. You can trust me on that.

Comment: @tawab_shakeel, I understand the code block, but you also changed the format as original format was ```for i in range(50): sleep(0.1)```. A oneliner which is valid in python. That would explain why the ```print``` is executed at the end.

Comment: @tawab_shakeel Your edit was what I initially intended to put in the question. I just forgot to format the code.

Comment: @thesuzan, so if you copy past the edited code block, it still does not work? I have tried it and it works.

Comment: @NicLaforge I tried the edited part too, didn't work it waited first and then printed

Comment: @NicLaforge No, the delay happens first then it prints the characters all at once without any delay.

Comment: That's what I meant

Comment: It works if you remove the end="0"

Comment: I am speechless about this as I dont see why it would not work. I do believe you about your indentation is correct, but would you mind trying my solution below which will move it inside a method just to confirming more.. let me know

Comment: @AmartyaGaur , yes. But I don't want the line to break every time it loops

Comment: Please try and confirm with the below answer code. If it does not work, can you provide how you run it and which python version you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flush output of print function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As python is linebuffered it will wait for a newline before printing the stdout.

**Solution 1:**

Add PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 to your env.var:

```
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

This will allow the output to be immediately dumped

**Solution 2:**

As you are using python >= 3 you can use the flush=True

```
for i in range(50):
    sleep(0.1)
    print("#", end="", flush=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything. I get the same result; the delay first, and then the characters are printed, without any delay in between.

Comment: Are you running from terminal?

Comment: I'm using a linux subsystem on windows to run the code with Python 3.6.7. But, I also tried it on the anaconda prompt with Python 3.7.3. Both gave me the same results

Comment: I don't understand that. Do I add "export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" at the beginning of my code? That gives me an error.

Comment: No run it from the terminal before calling your code. Or even better set it in your bashrc file so it remains

Comment: Try with the flush parameter

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Would you care to help me understand why.

Comment: Ok good! I explain that by setting the PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 the output would be immediately dumped. Python by default is linebuffered. Therefore it will wait for a new line to print the output. Using ```flush```, it will dump the output right away. If you always want this behaviour, you can set the env.v.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Python is linebuffered. As long as you `print` without a newline, output is collected but not shown. You must forcefully `flush` the output.

```
from time import sleep
print("starting the progress bar")


for i in range(50):
    sleep(0.1)
    print("#", end = '', flush=True)
```

Note in that whatever you use to *view* the output might be linebuffered as well. This cannot be changed from within your script.

Comment: This will produce the same result. It will only print at the end.

Comment: @NicLaforge I had missed that requirement. Try the new version.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution on reddit.

[reddit comment on why it doesn't work and how beginners fall into the same pitfall](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/5ebkq6/what_does_pythonunbuffered1_do/dabf9bh/)

So, it has something to do with buffering.

Here's the code that would work;

```
from time import sleep
print("starting the progress bar")


for i in range(50):
    sleep(0.1)
    print("#", end = '', flush = True)
```

Comment: or you can use `python -u`. This also forces output to be unbuffered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-u` option when running your program.

```
$ man python3


PYTHON(1)                                                            PYTHON(1)

...

       -u     Force  the  stdout  and  stderr  streams to be unbuffered.  This
              option has no effect on the stdin stream.
```

Run like this: `python3 -u file.py`

---

Alternatively, you can set the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable in your shell

```
       PYTHONUNBUFFERED
              If this is set to a non-empty string it is equivalent to  speci-
              fying the -u option.
```

Like so: `PYTHONUNBUFFERED="yes" python3 file.py`

---

Lastly, you can use `flush=True` as other answers have mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Just add *import time* above the code. I was coding a count down system-

```
import time
for i in range(10,0,-1):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
print("yayy! the code works")
```