# Why doesn't print() work in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, loops, visual-studio-code, printing

I'm trying to make a `while True`-loop that repeatedly prints a string:

```
from time import sleep
while True:
    sleep(1)
    print("test", end="")
```

But it doesn't print anything when running it with VSC. Running it with the IDLE works for me, a friend also tried it and for him, it's the other way round.

Why does this happen?

Comment: The output may be buffered, the only way to ensure it prints immediately is to pass `flush=True` to print.

Comment: Ah, this works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `stdout` is [buffered](https://www.enricozini.org/blog/2021/python/python-output-buffering/), meaning that prints to `stdout` don't appear on the console until a newline is printed, the buffer is full, or if the buffer is flushed.

You have three options:

1. Get rid of the end parameter in the `print()` statement, as `print()` statements implicitly add newlines.
2. Flush the buffer using `sys.stdout.flush()`:

```py
import sys
from time import sleep

while True:
    sleep(1)
    print("test", end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

3. Use `flush=True` in the `print()` statement.

Comment: Just adding ```flush=True``` also works, my question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56896710/does-time-sleep-not-work-inside-a-for-loop-with-a-print-function-using-the/56896956

Comment: None of these work running via the vscode tester. Do you know how make them work there?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would post a new question if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [Does "time.sleep()" not work inside a for loop with a print function using the "end" attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56896710/does-time-sleep-not-work-inside-a-for-loop-with-a-print-function-using-the/56896956), the output needs to be forced using `print("test", end="", flush=True)`

Comment: If it is a duplicate, then close it as a duplicate. Don't post a link to the duplicate as an answer.